# HADOOP exceeding memory limit

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am receiving follow message under the unhealthy node section.

```
 1/1 local-dirs usable space is below configured utilization percentage/no more usable space [ /tmp/hadoop-User/nm-local-dir : used space above threshold of 90.0% ]
1/1 log-dirs usable space is below configured utilization percentage/no more usable space [ C:/hadoop-3.3.0/logs/userlogs : used space above threshold of 90.0% ]
```

I saw a solution previously, either clean up the disk where the hadoop node is running on or increase the limit in yarn file. I do not want to increase the value in yarn file, I want to clean up the disk. Can anybody tell me what should I delete, i.e. where is the location on which hadoop is running its jobs?

Comment: The error gives you the location of two folders. What's your question?

Comment: This error occurs due to available disk space on the node exceeding yarn's max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage default value of 90.0%. It can be solved in two ways:
Either clean up the disk that the unhealthy node is running on, or increase the threshold in yarn-site.xml
I managed to solve it by increasing value in yarn file but how can I clean up the disk that the unhealthy node is running on, where is that disk? @OneCricketeer

Comment: You are the one running Hadoop. The error says you only have one server and one disk. Open Windows file explorer